# What are the challenges and the importance to build an explicit K3 metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Calabi-Yau manifolds are an important set of spaces in physics and mathematics. However, some of their geometrical features are yet mysterious or unknown. In particular, beyond the nature of mirror symmetry, we lack an explicit expression for the one of the simplest Calabi-Yau manifolds, the K3.

Context: Kerr black holes are solutions to the Einstein field equations describing rotating black holes. What thing is described by a K3 metric? Due to my background on string theory too, I believe CY spaces describe varieties with singularities, but of course, I can not see the global view (and beyond that of a pure mathematician), and I do know this question matters not only in string theory...But due to some applications, I presume, the K3 metric could help to understand better. Anyway, I am not a pure mathematician...So,

1. Why to build a K3 metric is a "hard" problem? In particular, why technically twistor approximations are not good enough to build up the K3 metric, and what is lacking.
2. Why is important to solve this problem? I mean, here, what are the kind of problems would be simplified with the aid of an explicit K3 metric.

Comment: Do you know why Ricci flat Kahler metric exists?

Comment: OH, yes...! I should add why this question matters should be added in the response.

Comment: @johnma, Reading this it is impossible to know even what background the OP has, or anything else, really. One can ask essentially the same question for every open problem.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really matter to me why this question is interesting to the OP, when this is a famous open problem. The question is missing context, but probably not the context that hardmath suggested. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: Twistor theory, e.g., was used to approximate K3 metric (Hitchin, 1984). However, I can not imagine what are the difficulties to get not only an approximation but the exact K3 metric. I mean, what or why a closed and exact expression (likely non polynomial, I pressume) to this K3 surface can benefit mathematics or physics? As far as I know, as an outsider of pure mathematics (I am a physicist), I want to know, specially, what kind of problems can help knowing this metric. Of course, I have some pieces of the answer, not the whole one, this is not a field I was too much interested in...

Comment: For instance, Kerr black holes are solutions to the Einstein field equations describing rotating black holes. What thing is described by a K3 metric? Due to my background on string theory too, I believe CY spaces describe varieties with singularities, but of course, as Ma says, I can not see the global view, and I do know this question matters not only in string theory...But due to some applications, I presume, the K3 metric could help to understand better. Anyway, I am not a pure mathematician...So, I decided to ask here instead in physics stack exchange.

Comment: You should put these into the question instead of the comment @riemannium

Comment: @JohnMa:  I appreciate the added context and have withdrawn my vote to close.  Upvoted.